# how do i assign data received from post request to an observable? - IONIC3

Tags: angular, rest, ionic3, observable, apprequests

Hey guys so i am building an IONIC 3 application which is to access an API and make POST and GET requests. I have a problem in subscribing the data received from the POST request to an Observable variable. My objective of the code is to send a post request and display a list of products from the data returned. The following is my code, however i am unable to subscribe the data to the observable as i do with the get request:

```
public products_detail: Observable<any>;

 this.httpClient.post("http://www.xxx.asia/app_test/detail_shop_meals.json", postData)
      this.products_detail.subscribe(data => {
          json_load = data.toString();
          this.meal_available = data;
          shop_name = document.getElementById("shop_name").innerHTML = data.shop_name;
          food_type = document.getElementById("food_type").innerHTML = data.shop_description;
          fee = document.getElementById("fee").innerHTML = "฿"+ data.price
          console.log('my data: ', data);
          console.log('look here:', data.detail_meals_popular[0].name)
          //return this.products_detail = json_load;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

and the html to display the products is as follows:

```
<h4>Most Popular</h4>
      <ul>
        <li ion-item *ngFor="let x of (products_detail | async)?.detail_meals_popular" (click)="item()">
          <div class="list_circle">
              <img src="assets/imgs/item2.png" alt="food">
          </div>
          <div class="list_circle_detail">
            <h5>{{ x.name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ x.description }}</p>
            <strong>฿ {{ x.price }}</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

id like to use the observable variable to list the products in my html, thank you in advance for the help guys :-)

Comment: where is `products_detail` set? is it the http post call?

Comment: @SurajRao products_detail is an observable variable and its set just under the export class

Comment: No, it's not initialized there. It's only declared. You need to subscribe on the Observable that is returned by the call to `this.httpClient.post(...)`. And don't use document.getElementById(): change the state of your component, and use the template to display that state.